Perturbation theory of Anderson impurity model
I’ve been learning about DMFT(Dynamical mean field theories) these days and have encountered  rather simple questions in many-body perturbation theory.
It is about IPT Impurity solver (applying iterated perturbation theory to solve for single impurity Anderson model, or SIAM). Here, the authors provided the self-energy of SIAM under second order perturbation theory, which reads:
$$
\Sigma\left(i \omega_n\right)=\frac{U}{2}+U^2 \int_0^\beta d \tau e^{i \omega_n \tau} \mathcal{G}_0(\tau)^3
$$
And I am wondering how can we derive it and how can we generalize it to higher-order perturbation theory?
An answer will be of great help to me, and I would like to express my sincere gratitude in advance.
